# C# two separate values in array for sorting

Tags: c#

Another application sends me unsortable values. So i did this:

```
string[] myarray = newString[size];
for (uint32 i = 0; i<sizOfIncoming;i++){
    myarray[i]=incoming[i].location.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(incoming[i].id.ToSTring();)
}
array.Sort(myarray);
for (uint32 x = 0; x<sizeOfIncoming;x++){
    Console.WriteLine(myarray[x]);
}
```

But now i need not only "location" but also "id"

the incoming would look like this:

```
5,A
1,X
3,N
2,Z
4,E
```

and in the end i need it like this:

```
1,X
2,Z
3,N
4,E
5,A
```

How can i do this?

P.S C# newbie

Comment: What is the type of incoming? List?

Comment: i used incoming as an alias for this `FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] ftdiDeviceList = new FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftdiDeviceCount];`

ftdiDeviceList  is replaced by incoming in my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using LINQ you can decide which part of your object you want to order by:

If your incoming array has 'id' and 'location' fields, here's how you sort by the ID:

```
var sortedArray = incoming.OrderBy(x => x.id).ToArray();
```

Or if you want to order by location:

```
var sortedArray = incoming.OrderBy(x => x.location).ToArray();
```

Then print the contents:

```
for (int i = 0; i<sortedArray.Length;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{sortedArray[i].id} {sortedArray[i].location}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sortedData = myarray
    .Select(v => v.Split(','))
    .Select(v => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(v[0]), Location = v[1] })
    .OrderBy(v => v.Id)
    .ThenBy(v => v.Location);
```

You may need to add `using System.Linq;`to your file first to get this to work. This code works by using [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) to project the original collection into an collection of string arrays. Then, for each string array we have created, we create a new [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with "Id" and "Location" properties so it is easier to work with. Finally we can then sort the collection first by the "Id" property and then by the "Location" property.